# A Naive Prime Test Implementation - Problem with Table

Tags: list-manipulation, map

I tried to write a simple function which implements a naive primality test.

```
NaivePrimeTest[num_] := 
 num >= 2 && (Not[
    Fold[Or, 
     Map[Divisible[num, #] &, Table[i, {i, 2, Floor[Sqrt[num]]}]]]])
```

It worked okay for large numbers.

```
In[2]:= NaivePrimeTest[10]

Out[2]= False

In[5]:= NaivePrimeTest[4]

Out[5]= False
```

But for 2 and 3, the table is empty and the function failed to run as expected.

```
In[3]:= NaivePrimeTest[2]

Out[3]= ! Fold[Or, {}]

In[4]:= NaivePrimeTest[3]

Out[4]= ! Fold[Or, {}]
```

But I am not sure about a better way to handle this.

Also, for large numbers, the cost of using `Table` is significant.

Could you give me some suggestions on what to change or optimize?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can `Apply` the `Or` instead of `Fold`-ing it:

```
naivePrimeTest[num_] := 
 num >= 2 && (Not[
    Or @@ 
     Map[Divisible[num, #] &, Table[i, {i, 2, Floor[Sqrt[num]]}]]])

naivePrimeTest /@ Range[20] == PrimeQ@Range@20
(*  True  *)
```

As for efficiency, it's the "naive test"?  Just what constraints are there?  Why have it be fast, when it's known to be inefficient?  Here is a shorter code text, using the `Listable` attribute of `Divisible`, instead of `Map`-ping it:

```
naivePrimeTest[num_] := 
 num >= 2 && (Not[Or @@ Divisible[num, Range[2, Floor[Sqrt[num]]]]])
```

For true efficiency, use `PrimeQ`, but I assume that's out of bounds.

*Update*

There is a way to abort `Table` as soon as you find the number is composite. That's a more efficient naive test (*update:* replaced `Table` with `Do`, which is slightly faster on large `num` — thanks @BenIzd!):

```
naivePrimeTest[num_] := 
 num >= 2 && (Do[
    If[Divisible[num, i],
     Return[False, And]],
    {i, 2, Floor[Sqrt[num]]}]; True)
```

<s>It's not that much more efficient than the listable version, it seems (virtually indistinguishable).</s> My eyes tricked me and I missed a zero.  This way bests the listable one.

Comment: `AnyTrue` feels ignored :)

Comment: @Ben Yep. I learned Mma too long ago, I guess. :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Despite it is the naive test, constructing a whole table when the number is divisible by 2 is a bit absurd.
I still want my implementation to be efficient as much as possible. Also, I can learn a lot of MMA that I don't know by doing this.

Comment: @Ben The speed improvement in the update is a sensible sort of thing to pursue. I just didn't think of it at first. -- The `Return[value, func]` is not documented but you can find it on this site. I remember once seeing `Return[value, Module]` somewhere before this site existed, but I learned more about it from here. -- Thanks for the accept!

Comment: Continuing the story, it seems `Do` is miffed. ;)

Comment: @BenIzd I heard that using Do is generally not a good practice in MMA?

Comment: @Ben `Do` and `Table` are similar, except `Table` stores the result of each iteration. In this case the results are not needed, so `Do` is probably the better choice, both in terms of expressing intent (don't need all the `True` results) and efficiency (don't waste memory). `Do` is sometimes the most efficient tool, but if you're using it to generate data, it almost never is. (`For` is another story and is almost never the most efficient solution.) Further, `Do` is procedural and folks tend to prefer a functional programming approach. Those are the main points; `Do` is slightly faster here.